# Leporello tips?

Tags: packages

Is it some packages to help users to create a leporello edition ?
To regard the creases, the long size paper, etc.
(leporello is an edition in accordeon)
i.e.: [example of leporello](http://www.designers-books.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/IMG_6569.jpg)

Comment: I knew *another* Leporello! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=INF9r5jju0A

Comment: The [`leaflet`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/leaflet) document class ([manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/leaflet/leaflet-manual.pdf)) might be of help. However, it seems it only supports up to six (virtual) pages and mostly the standard LaTeX page sizes.

Comment: Yes, this technique is a reference to the long list of dates of Don Juan, that Leporello presents to Donna Elvira on a long long paper sheet creased as an accordeon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By a curious coincidence, I just made the acquaintance of `pgfpages.sty`. As it turns out, with a little work it can do exactly this sort of layout -- and a good deal else besides.  I read about this in the PGF manual and looked at pgfpages.sty for inspiration. This has been a very interesting exercise! My apologies for the length of the code. Clearly, this could be tailored easily to your exact needs.

I've added some comments in the code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[papersize={7in,10in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{everypage}%% For fold marks

\pgfpagesdeclarelayout{Leporello16}
{
  \edef\pgfpageoptionheight{\the\paperheight} 
  \edef\pgfpageoptionwidth{\the\paperwidth}
  \edef\pgfpageoptionborder{0pt}
}
{
  \pgfpagesphysicalpageoptions
  {%
    logical pages=16,%
    physical height=\pgfpageoptionheight,%
    physical width=\pgfpageoptionwidth%
  }
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}
  {%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=.0625\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=\pgfphysicalheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.03125\pgfphysicalwidth}{.5\pgfphysicalheight}%
  }%
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{2}
  {%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=.0625\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=\pgfphysicalheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.09375\pgfphysicalwidth}{.5\pgfphysicalheight}%
  }%
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{3}
  {%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=.0625\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=\pgfphysicalheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.15625\pgfphysicalwidth}{.5\pgfphysicalheight}%
  }%
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{4}
  {%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=.0625\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=\pgfphysicalheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.21875\pgfphysicalwidth}{.5\pgfphysicalheight}%
  }%
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{5}
  {%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=.0625\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=\pgfphysicalheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.28125\pgfphysicalwidth}{.5\pgfphysicalheight}%
  }%
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{6}
  {%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=.0625\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=\pgfphysicalheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.34375\pgfphysicalwidth}{.5\pgfphysicalheight}%
  }%
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{7}
  {%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=.0625\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=\pgfphysicalheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.40625\pgfphysicalwidth}{.5\pgfphysicalheight}%
  }%
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{8}
  {%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=.0625\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=\pgfphysicalheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.46875\pgfphysicalwidth}{.5\pgfphysicalheight}%
  }%
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{9}
  {%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=.0625\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=\pgfphysicalheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.53125\pgfphysicalwidth}{.5\pgfphysicalheight}%
  }%
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{10}
  {%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=.0625\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=\pgfphysicalheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.59375\pgfphysicalwidth}{.5\pgfphysicalheight}%
  }%
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{11}
  {%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=.0625\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=\pgfphysicalheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.65625\pgfphysicalwidth}{.5\pgfphysicalheight}%
  }%
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{12}
  {%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=.0625\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=\pgfphysicalheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.71875\pgfphysicalwidth}{.5\pgfphysicalheight}%
  }%
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{13}
  {%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=.0625\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=\pgfphysicalheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.78125\pgfphysicalwidth}{.5\pgfphysicalheight}%
  }%
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{14}
  {%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=.0625\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=\pgfphysicalheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.84375\pgfphysicalwidth}{.5\pgfphysicalheight}%
  }%
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{15}
  {%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=.0625\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=\pgfphysicalheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.90625\pgfphysicalwidth}{.5\pgfphysicalheight}%
  }%
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{16}
  {%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=.0625\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=\pgfphysicalheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.96875\pgfphysicalwidth}{.5\pgfphysicalheight}%
  }%
}

%% Comment-out the following line while you prepare the content.
%% Uncomment-out the following line when you want to create the Leporello document.
\pgfpagesuselayout{Leporello16}[physical paper height = 10in, physical paper width = 112in]

\pagestyle{empty}

%% From everypage.sty -- adds the fold marks:
\AddEverypageHook{\tikz[remember picture,overlay] \draw[thin] (current page.north east) -- ++(0,-1);}

\begin{document}

\centering

\foreach \i in {1,...,16}{%
\resizebox{!}{2in}{\Huge\i}%
\clearpage
}

\end{document}
```

This is the end result, greatly reduced:

[image: Better illustration with fold marks.]

### Later

It occurred to me that this would be useless without fold marks. I have indicated, in a general sort of way, how to add them -- noted in the code. The first time you try this, you'll have to TeX it twice in order to see the fold marks.

### Much later

The OP has asked for a vertical example. Here is a 4-page example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[papersize={7in,10in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{everypage}%% For fold marks

\pgfpagesdeclarelayout{Leporello4v}
{
  \edef\pgfpageoptionheight{\the\paperheight} 
  \edef\pgfpageoptionwidth{\the\paperwidth}
  \edef\pgfpageoptionborder{0pt}
}
{
  \pgfpagesphysicalpageoptions
  {%
    logical pages=4,%
    physical height=\pgfpageoptionheight,%
    physical width=\pgfpageoptionwidth%
  }
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}
  {%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=0.25\pgfphysicalheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.5\pgfphysicalwidth}{.875\pgfphysicalheight}%
  }%
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{2}
  {%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=0.25\pgfphysicalheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.5\pgfphysicalwidth}{.625\pgfphysicalheight}%
  }%
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{3}
  {%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=0.25\pgfphysicalheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.5\pgfphysicalwidth}{.375\pgfphysicalheight}%
  }%
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{4}
  {%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=0.25\pgfphysicalheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.5\pgfphysicalwidth}{.125\pgfphysicalheight}%
  }%
}


\pgfpagesuselayout{Leporello4v}[physical paper height = 40in, physical paper width = 7in]

\pagestyle{empty}

%% From everypage.sty:
\AddEverypageHook{%
    \tikz[remember picture,overlay] \draw[thin] (current page.south east) -- ++(-1,0);%
}

\begin{document}

\centering

\foreach \i in {1,...,4}{%
\resizebox{!}{2in}{\Huge\i}%
\clearpage
}

\end{document}
```

And it looks like this:

[image: Vertical Leporello.]

Comment: I will test your code. The main problem that I have is to translate it in vertical mode. I have to create a Leporello like yours but in the vertical mode.

Comment: I have extended my response to include a vertical example.

Answer (score 3):

I do not know any package specifically designed for this purpose and closest thing that comes to my mind is what @doncherry mentioned in [their comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238734/leporello-tips#comment566697_238734). A not so elegant *workaround* can be achieved through the use of [geometry](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry?lang=en) and [multicol](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicol?lang=en) packages. `geometry` package helps you to define your particular paper size while `multicol` allows you to create virtual (not in technical sense) pages. Here is a minimal example with `\columnbreak` and option for paper folds indicator:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[paperwidth=50cm, paperheight=15cm,margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols*}{4}{
    \lipsum[1-4]
    \columnbreak
    \lipsum[5-10]
}
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[click to enlarge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYQaY.png)